# Control event not firing in a VBA Class Module

Tags: vba, class, ms-access, events

I have a problem getting any event firing from controls embedded in Class Modules in VBA Access. Despite many (many!) conversations in various forums related to this one, I haven't found any that help me. As far as I can tell I am following all their advices (mainly, I always use "Access.Control", "Access.Label" and so on so it is always the same library that is used, and the reference still exists at the moment the event should fire...), but it still doesn't fire!
In the same project I have the same problem in several classes; I will take the example of a group of labels on a form.

The load event of the form creates a first, big group like that:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

   ...

  set mGroups = new CDocTree
  mGroups.Make Me

End Sub
```

In CDocTree there are three  member variables declared like that:

```
Private WithEvents mVVPlan As CDocGroup
Private WithEvents mTestPlan As CDocGroup
Private mFrm As Form_FrmAlphaDocuments
```

and the method Make essentially does this:

```
Public Sub Make(frm As Access.Form)

  Set mFrm = frm

  With mFrm

    Set mVVPlan = New CDocGroup
    mVVPlan .Make .LblVVPlanBox, .LblVVPlanRef

    Set mTestPlan = New CDocGroup
    mTestPlan .Make .LblTestPlanBox, .LblTestPlanRef

  End With

End Sub
```

Finally the class CDocGroup is defined like that:

```
Private WithEvents mBox As Access.Label
Private WithEvents mRef As Access.Label

Public Event Clicked(grp As CDocGroup)

Public Sub Make(box As Access.Label, ref As Access.Label)

  ...

  Set mBox = box
  Set mRef = ref

End Sub

Private Sub mBox_Click()
  Debug.Print "Event Click fired in CDocGroup on " & mBox.Name
  RaiseEvent Clicked(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub mRef_Click()
  Debug.Print "Event Click fired in CDocGroup on " & mRef.Name
  RaiseEvent Clicked(Me)
End Sub
```

That's it: the code never gets in mBox_Click or mRef_Click. What do I do wrong?

Comment: In the past, I've had to stub those events in the Form module to get them to pass through to the class events (though I've read you shouldn't have to do this).  So put in a skeleton declaration, Private Sub lblBox_Click()...End Sub on the Form itself and see if it passes the events through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks VBlades, it does the trick.

Although it is infuriating that something like this should be necessary, I can indeed verify that if I put a declaration for some of the controls and not for others, my events fire only for the controls that have the empty event declaration in the form's module.

So to be clear, in the form's module, for each control that I need to react, I add an empty declaration:

```
Private Sub LblVVPlanBox_Click()

End Sub
```

No code at all in it, but now the event in my class fires and the code in the class is executed. It is kind of ugly, but still better than copying 20 times the same instructions in the form's module.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody comes across this post like me, trying to figure out why the events aren't firing, there is a far [simpler solution on another forum](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/888619-listbox-dblclick-event-not-firing-within-class-module).

Basically when you set your mBox / mRef in the class module do the following:

```
mBox.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
mRef.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
```

This will let the class module know, that there is an event it has to execute. So there is no need to declare all the subs in your forms code.